# Insert data into table from form not working, it shows that there has been rows inserted, but it's all NULL

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

new to coding, but I got a project: I have a form that I want to use to insert data into a table on my database. I have a function that grabs the values from the elements and puts into an object, then use a promise. Then on the server part, I have a POST that takes that and inserts into the database table.

```
<script>
        function addProperty(){
            var property = {};
            property.propid = document.getElementById("propid").value;
            property.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            property.owner = document.getElementById("owner").value;
            property.size = document.getElementById("size").value;
            property.streetnum = document.getElementById("streetnum").value;
            property.streetname = document.getElementById("street").value;
            property.city = document.getElementById("city").value;
            property.province = document.getElementById("prov").value;
            property.country = document.getElementById("country").value;
            property.parking = document.getElementById("parking").value;
            property.ptrans = document.getElementById("public").value;
            property.description = document.getElementById("description").value;

            fetch("http://localhost:4000/html/propertyform.html", {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(property),
            })
            .then(function (res) {
                window.alert("New property added!");
                location.href = "http://localhost:4000/html/owner.html"
            })
            .catch(function(res) {
                console.log(res);
            })
        }
    </script>
```

The server part:

```
app.post("/html/propertyform.html", (req, res) => {
  var params = [
    req.body.propid,
    req.body.name,
    req.body.owner,
    req.body.size,
    req.body.streetnum,
    req.body.streetname,
    req.body.city,
    req.body.province,
    req.body.country,
    req.body.parking,
    req.body.ptrans,
    req.body.description
  ];

  db.run(
    "INSERT INTO properties(id_prop, prop_name, id_user, size, street_num, street_name, city, province, country, garage, public, description) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
    params,
    function (err, rows) {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(200).json({ error: err.message});
      }
      res.json(rows);
    }
  );
});
```

So when i hit the button, it has the prompt appear and says it added the property, then redirects me to the other page. this is working fine, but the catch method isn't because i don't see the results on the terminal. Next, there is data being inserted into the table, a row each time like its supposed to, but it is all NULL! No matter what i enter in the form, I am only getting rows of NULL values being inserted into my table in the database. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but maybe there is an answer for this?

Comment: The insert statement looks ok. What happens if you insert a dummy `params` array like `["1","name", ... ]`?

Comment: Also `db.run` doesn't return a value for `rows` to the callback like that - https://github.com/TryGhost/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#runsql--param---callback

Comment: thank you, I fixed the db.run part and tried the dummy array. the array did not work, nor did any null rows get inserted. then i tried the code with the dummy array normally without being in the POST, and it worked how it was supposed to, so not sure what next?